# $A$ and $B$ are $3\times3$ matrices. $3A-B^2=0$ and $A^2-4B=0$, find possible determinants for A and B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

$$3A-B^2=0$$
$$A^2-4B=0$$
I don't know how to solve that. I've tried solving for some general $3a_{ij}$ and express the element that is deducted but it doesn't get me anywhere...

Comment: Remember: If $X,Y$ are square matrices of the same dimension, then $det(XY)=det(X)det(Y)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have $$3A=B^2,$$hence $$3^3\det A=(\det B)^2.$$ Similarly, $$A^2=4B,$$hence $$(\det A)^2=4^3\det B.$$Can you solve this system on $\det A$ and $\det B$?

**edit**

The solution; let $a=\det A$ and $b=\det B$, then the system writes
$$3^3a=b^2,\quad 4^3b=a^2.$$ Square the first equation:

$$b^4=3^6a^2 = 3^6\cdot 4^3 b.$$
The first case is $a=b=0$, which is trivial; suppose that $a\ne0$ and $b\ne 0$, which gives$$b^3=3^6\cdot 4^3$$ or $b=36$, which implies $a=b^2/27 = 48$.

Comment: Why is $(det B)^2=3^3det A$ ?

Comment: @Agami because for square matrices $n\times n$ you have $\det (XY)=\det X\det Y$ and $\det (\lambda X) = \lambda^n\det X$.

Comment: I got to $$(det A)^2 = 64det B$$ $$27det A = (det B)^2$$
I managed to wolfram a solution out of it but I don't know how to calculate one myself without using a calculator